# Desktop Icon-Text appears unreadable

Tags: windows-8.1, desktop

My desktop appearance changed randomly today, it looks ugly and unreadable.
I am on Windows 8.1 with 2 screens.

Here is what i tried:

- Delete IconCache.db
- Restarting
- Changing ClearText
- Scaling (in the windows settings)

Sadly nothing did help. Does anybody have an idea how to solve this?

This is how it looks like:

[image: This is how it looks]

Edit:
Grafik Card: Intel HD Graphics 4000, Driver version is 9.17.10.2843 (Windows tells me that my driver is up to date)

Comment: Could you please add your graphics card and graphics driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just guessing here - but it looks, like Windows tries to anti-alias your text against a dark/black background...

Are you using some custom software to change your Wallpaper? (some kind of animation, or webpage?)

Try setting your Wallpaper to a plain color in Windows (black or white), if everything is good, try a different Wallpaper set in Windows (not some other App)

Comment: You are right. if i use black as Background everything looks fine. I just switched the background a view times and now my icon text renders black instead of white on the yellow-orange background of my original post (the default windows 8.1 background). All thought i didn't use any 3rd Party software to change it, i didn't even touch it at all. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

From [Fuzzy Text/Icons after upgrading to Windows 8.1](http://windowsforum.com/threads/fuzzy-text-icons-after-upgrading-to-windows-8-1-solution-here.178515/) :

After updating to 8.1,
fuzzy text and fuzzy icons in notification area
are due to 8.1's new "improved" DPI Scaling options and affects many people.

If you just upgraded to 8.1 and now your fonts look weird, text is harder to read, or tray icons look fuzzy/blurry, then this should fix it:

- Right click desktop, choose "Screen resolution"
- Click "Make text and other items larger or smaller"
- Check the box "Let me choose one scaling level for all of my displays"
- Click the "Apply" buttin below the above setting

You will now have to log out and then back in to test to see if this fixed your DPI Scaling issues.

Comment: I just tried this, sadly it didn't change anything :/

Comment: (1) Is your size 100 percent? (2) If you uncheck "Let me choose one scaling level for all of my displays" and choose "Icons" from "Change only the text size" drop-down list, what value do you have for size? And if you change this value and "Apply" what happens?

Comment: It is 100% i changed the scaling (as i mentioned in the question to different values, without any effect). The size is 9 for Icons other values do not change the appearance (just the size). Apply results in either a log out prompt or a please wait screen.

Comment: What happens if you logout and back with another font size for icons?

Comment: Sadly only the size changes after the please wait screen, logging out and in does not show any further effect

Comment: This used to work in Windows 8, but apparently no longer in 8.1. The only other idea I have is not to rely on the Windows graphics driver and download the [Intel latest driver](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&ProductFamily=Graphics&ProductLine=Laptop+graphics+drivers&ProductProduct=3rd+Generation+Intel%C2%AE+Core%E2%84%A2+Processors+with+Intel%C2%AE+HD+Graphics+4000), currently version 15.33.8.64.3345. Create first a system restore point.

Comment: I use a HP device and it does not accept the current version. But i tried the latest that was available on the manufacture homepage. But the problem persists.

Comment: Does [this text](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/28310-dpi-scaling-size-change-displays-windows-8-1-a.html) help in any way? Try changing the DPI to other values to see if there is an improvement (if Windows just got it wrong).

Comment: Also, do you have an external monitor?

Comment: I have an external Monitor as i mentioned in the question. Sadly the link did not help

Comment: Do you have this problem when booting without the external monitor? If you do, then I don't know of a solution. If without it you don't have the problem, then how is this monitor defined?

Comment: Booting without external monitor does not help either :/

Comment: Did you try custom DPI values above and below 100%?

Comment: I can't set DPI values below 100%, but i tried out some above 100%